# How to detect harmful gas occurence in carboy bottle

Tags: water

To fill with drinkable water, I have lots of empty 19lt carboy bottles. Since they came from different people and companies, I have to check their healthiness to decide wheter they can be sterilise for reuse or not.

I need to detect if a 19lt carboy bottle was used previously for gas, lpg, diesel etc. or is there any other harmful chemical (such as urine) in it.

What could be the cheapest and trustable solution for it? Could I use gas sensors or infrared imaging or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I agree with Jerry. But I also wish you **moved** that, not closed. It's interesting and very useful in real life.

Comment: What is the material of the bottles?

Comment: Actually I ain't know what the material exactly is. As far as I know, the material is carbon based. I am sure that you are familier with this kind of bottle. You can find a sample image here: http://cdn.tbplatform.com/company/727/products/4392/600-carboy_drinking_water_19_lt.jpg

Comment: some information on detection of organic compounds can be found here http://www.epa.gov/oust/pubs/esa-ch6.pdf includes detailed explanations and cost assessment. note that costs are for large batches. equipment will probably be expensive.

Comment: Hi Daniel, That link explains lots of things. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Gas sensors are probably too specific. Infrared imaging is going to have to take account of the carboy material itself. However, sampling the air and performing a gc/ms analysis could work - basically its headspace analysis.

Comment: Thank you very much Epicentre. Since I am not familiar with these techniques and devices, I can't decide it is suitable for us or not. Could you please guide me for these devices and techniques. Especially cost is the main parameter. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pertinaks I suggest you contact a chemical analysis laboratory in your general area to find out the cost. It will probably be considerably more than the cost of the bottle itself. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_chromatography and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headspace_technology may help you understand the technique.